# jquery cycle2 videos AND images together

Tags: jquery, video, youtube, slideshow, cycle

I have jquery cycle2 working on a site with images, separately I can also have it working with youtube videos. But I need to have images and videos in the slideshow at the same time.

Just wondering is this even possible? Whenever I have both in together the images never show up only videos.

Answer (score 3):

Just to let you guys know! This has been updated by plugin author and now its part of Plugin. So you can add images and youtube video in same slider without tweaking plugin files.

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/video.php

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but as far as I know not without tweaking jquery.cycle2.video.js.

Change line 27

from:

```
var markup, slide = $(this), url = slide.attr( 'href' );
```

to:

```
var markup, slide = $(this).find('a.youtube'), url = slide.attr( 'href' );
```

Next change the data-cycle-slides Attribute

from:

```
data-cycle-slides=">a"
```

to:

```
data-cycle-slides=">div.item"
```

Finally wrap all slideshow items into div containers

Video Container:

```
<div class="item">
    <a class="youtube" href="https://www.youtube.com/v/addYoutubeVideoIdHere?version=3&hl=en_US&rel=0">Video 1</a>
</div>
```

Image Container:

```
<div class="item">
    <img src="addImagehere.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: Will youtube autoplay and autostop work with this update? Thanks